# how to integrate $\int\frac{1}{x^2-12x+35}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate following

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2-12x+35}dx?$$
What I did is here:

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2-12x+35}=\int\frac{dx}{(x-6)^2-1}$$

substitute $x-6=t$, $dx=dt$
$$=\int\frac{dt}{t^2-1}$$
partial fraction decomposition,
$$=\int{1\over 2}\left(\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{t+1}\right)dt$$
$$=\frac12(\ln|1-t|-\ln|1+t|)+c$$
$$=\frac12\left(\ln\left|\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right|\right)+c$$
substitute back to $t$
$$=\frac12\ln\left|\frac{7-x}{x-5}\right|+c$$

I am not sure if my answer correct. Can I integrate this without substitution?  Thank you

Comment: You can just differentiate it to see if it is correct

Comment: You changed signs in a rather odd way from line 8 to line 9 ...

Comment: @DonAntonio is my answer correct?

Comment: Well, yes it is...but only because you have that absolute value there. Why did you change the sign, though? In other cases you can get a completely wrong answer...

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you sir. I found my error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you skip the substitution?  Certainly!

$\frac {1}{x^2 - 12 x + 35} = \frac {1}{(x-7)(x-5)} = \frac {A}{x-7} + \frac {B}{x-5}$

$A+B = 0\\
-5A - 7B = 1\\
A = \frac {1}{2}, B = -\frac {1}{2}$

$12\int \frac {1}{x-7} - \frac {1}{x-5} \ dx\\
\frac 12 (\ln |x-7| - \ln |x-5|)\\
\frac 12 \ln \left|\frac {x-7}{x-5}\right|$

Comment: thanks. my answer is slightly different $|7-x|$ in place of $|x-7| $ will it matter?

Comment: The expressions inside the absolute values are the negative on one another.  But the absolute value makes them equal.

Comment: ok, I got the point. thank you very much

Comment: @SamulGonjo You can use the identity $\frac{1}{n(n+k)}=\frac{1}{k} (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+k})$. Here we choose $k=(x-5)-(x-7)=2$ and $n=x-7$.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

You can do that without substitution. Use partial fractions by factorizing denominator:$x^2-12x+35=(x-5)(x-7)$
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2-12x+35}=\int \frac{dx}{(x-7)(x-5)}$$
$$=\int\frac12\left( \frac{1}{x-7}-\frac{1}{x-5}\right)dx$$
$$=\frac12(\ln\left| x-7\right|-\ln\left| x-5\right|)$$
$$=\frac12\ln\left| \frac{x-7}{x-5}\right|+C$$